# Изменить цвет изображения

Tags: css

Возможно ли в такой ситуации изменить только цвет изображения, а не весь `div` блок?

```
<div class="button_icon icon_object" id="object_button_id"></div>
```

Изображение в классе `icon_object`. Фильтр `brightness(0)` влияет на весь блок. Делать вложенный `div` не позволит написанная система.

Comment: Да, можно. Было бы стремление решать задачу. А технически - CSS дает множество путей для этого. Или `backdrop-filter`... или `background-blend-mode`... или `::before` с `background` + `position` + `z-index` + `filter`.

Comment: А что делать, если изображение белое, а нужно сделать черным? Фон прозрачный.

Comment: Для начала, я бы посоветовал прочитать документацию о тех CSS-свойствах которые указаны в предыдущем комментарии, и попробовать применить тот подход который больше понравится (насколько знаю, каждый из них позволяет инвертировать фоновое изображение). Далее - действовать по результатам попытки, например дополнять вопрос сутью проблемы (если помимо лени, настоящая проблема вообще появится, что вряд ли - вероятнее, у тебя все получится сразу). Ну, либо сидеть тут и ждать ответ с копипастом из MDN.

Comment: Для `background-blend-mode` нужно ставить фон, а для `backdrop-filter` - вложенный блок.

Comment: Первое утверждение верно, второе ошибочно. `backdrop-filter` влияет на элементы в css-слоях ниже (не на вложенные).

Comment: _«backdrop-filter влияет на элементы в css-слоях ниже (не на вложенные)»_ - https://jsbin.com/nugofegisa/edit?html,css,output

Comment: белое в чёрное - filter: invert(); вроде